# Building gdbserver for RISCV

Tags: riscv, gdbserver

I would like to build `gdbserver` to run on a RISCV platform and allow serial attachment from a Linux development machine.

I have tried to build various repositories e.g. `riscv-binutils-gdb` which I obtained from GitHUB via `git`. I am using a riscv toolchain that I downloaded from sifive. In the end I would like to test `gdbserver` on the sifive hifive 1 rev A01 that I purchased.

Here are the build commands I am using:

```
CC=$RISCV_BIN/$RISCV_PREFIX"gcc" 
AR=$RISCV_BIN/$RISCV_PREFIX"ar" 
./configure --prefix=$RISCV_BIN/$RISCV_PREFIX --target=riscv64-unknown-elf --host=riscv64-unknown-elf --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

I would expect this to build `gdbserver` and its prerequisites, but I get errors such as:

> /home/mroths/riscv-binutils-gdb/libiberty/./unlink-if-ordinary.c:67: undefined reference to `lstat'

I assume that I am not invoking the build correctly, but any assistance would be appreciated.
If there is a better repository to start with, please let me know that as well.

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2019, gdbserver has not been ported to RISC-V yet.  As a result it won't build.